# ListViewGroups not working correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working with a ListView control in Windows Forms using C# and .NET 3.5. I have several items that I'm adding to this ListView control, and I have functionality in place that is supposed to allow the user to select different ways to group the items in the list. However, sometimes items get dumped into the automatically generated "Default" group for no explicable reason.

The code is too large to just put here, but let me explain what I'm doing algorithmically. Suppose we're starting with a ListView that contains items and may or may not already contain groups.

1. Cycle through every item and set
   it's Group property to null.
2. Empty the ListView's Groups
   collection.
3. Add new Groups to the ListView's
   Group collection.
4. Cycle through every item and set the
   Group property using a value
   obtained from the ListView's Group
   collection via index.

I've stepped through the code and observed everything as it should be. With each item it obtains the appropriate group from the ListView's Group collection and sets the Group property of the item, yet sometimes they end up listed under the "Default" group.

Has anyone else ever observed this or have any theories as to why it might be happening?

Comment: Does this happen in a predictable way?  Specifically, given a particular test set of items, is it always the same items that get dumped in the "Default" group?  If you progressively remove items from that test set, do the same items (of those still there) still get dumped in "Default," or different ones?

Comment: Yes. Once you get the pattern it's easy to reproduce.

Comment: I realise the code is too large to reproduce, but if the behaviour is reproducible, can you strip it back to a case where there are two items in the test set, one of which gets grouped correctly and one of which does not?  If so, could you post these two items, together with the code which adds the groups and sets the Group property for each item?  Alternatively, you say "once you get the pattern it's easy to reproduce" -- does this mean you've identified a pattern to the mis-groupings?  Can you describe that pattern?

Comment: I was able to avoid the issue entirely by dumping and recreating all the items when I need to change their groups around. Leads me to believe there's some sort of finesse required to changing the group of an item that has already had one. Couldn't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: I wonder if you aren't somehow giving it one of the *old* groups - maybe some timing thing? Hard to say without example code for steps 1-4. See my reply for code that does the same 1-4, but which I can't get to break.

Comment: Items should only be landing in the Default group if their Group property is null. Can you debug your app and confirm that this is the case? If so, there is an issue with your step 4 - the logic that assigns the Group may be failing for some reason. Try sticking a conditional breakpoint on that line, breaking if Group is null.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound familiar, and I can't reproduce (see below, which follows your approach). Can you post anything related to your "update the groups" code?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program {
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        ListView lv;
        Button btn;

        Form form = new Form {
            Controls = {
                (lv = new ListView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                      ShowGroups = true}),
                (btn = new Button { Dock = DockStyle.Bottom,
                      Text = "Scramblle" })
            }
        };
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
            lv.Items.Add("Item " + i);
        }
        btn.Click += delegate {
            // 1: Cycle through every item and set it's Group
            // property to null.
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items) {
                item.Group = null;
            }
            // 2: Empty the ListView's Groups collection.
            lv.Groups.Clear();
            // 3: Add new Groups to the ListView's Group collection.
            int groupCount = rand.Next(lv.Items.Count) + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
                lv.Groups.Add("grp" + i, "Group " + i);
            }
            // 4: Cycle through every item and set the Group property
            // using a value obtained from the ListView's Group collection
            // via index.
            foreach (ListViewItem item in lv.Items) {
                item.Group = lv.Groups[rand.Next(groupCount)];
            }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening on multiple threads?

It sounds like you might be adding some ListViewItems with Groups taken before the the groups were cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes... It happened to me too. Try to set the Group before you add the item. I mean when you initialize the ListViewItem you add to the constructor the group it takes part of. That way is going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have seen similar behavior. The solution I followed is based on the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups.aspx).

```
public partial class ListViewExtended : ListView
{
   private Collection<Dictionary<string, ListViewGroup>> groupTables = new Collection<Dictionary<string,ListViewGroup>>();

   public ListViewExtended()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Create groups for each column of the list view.
   /// </summary>
   public void CreateGroups()
   {
      CreateGroups(false);
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Create groups for each column of the list view.
   /// </summary>
   public void CreateGroups(bool reset)
   {
      if (OSFeature.Feature.IsPresent(OSFeature.Themes))
      {
         if (reset)
         {
            this.groupTables.Clear();
         }

         for (int column = 0; column < this.Columns.Count; column++)
         {
            Dictionary<string, ListViewGroup> groups = new Dictionary<string, ListViewGroup>();

            foreach (ListViewItem item in this.Items)
            {
               string subItemText = item.SubItems[column].Text;

               // Use the initial letter instead if it is the first column.
               if (column == 0)
               {
                  subItemText = subItemText.Substring(0, 1).ToUpperInvariant();
               }

               if (!groups.ContainsKey(subItemText))
               {
                  groups.Add(subItemText, new ListViewGroup(subItemText) { Name = subItemText });
               }
            }

            this.groupTables.Add(groups);
         }
      }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Sets the list view to the groups created for the specified column.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="column"></param>
   public void SetGroups(int column)
   {
      if (OSFeature.Feature.IsPresent(OSFeature.Themes))
      {
         try
         {
            this.BeginUpdate();
            this.Groups.Clear();

            if (column == -1)
            {
               this.ShowGroups = false;
            }
            else
            {
               this.ShowGroups = true;
               Dictionary<string, ListViewGroup> groups = groupTables[column];
               this.Groups.AddRange(groups.Values.OrderBy(g => g.Name).ToArray());

               foreach (ListViewItem item in this.Items)
               {
                  string subItemText = item.SubItems[column].Text;

                  // For the Title column, use only the first letter.
                  if (column == 0)
                  {
                     subItemText = subItemText.Substring(0, 1).ToUpperInvariant();
                  }

                  item.Group = groups[subItemText];
               }

               groups.Values.ForEach<ListViewGroup>(g => g.Header = String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, "{0} ({1})", g.Name, g.Items.Count));
            }
         }
         finally
         {
            this.EndUpdate();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In the code that actually adds the items to the listview, you want to do something like this:

```
this.itemsListView.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
this.itemsListView.CreateGroups(true);
this.itemsListView.SetGroups(0); // Group by the first column by default.
```